# Parse.com, how to store user history for past 30 days efficiently?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to keep track of a daily "swallow" count, and the user needs to be able to see the swallow count for any of the last 30 days, but the data beyond 30 days can be tossed. There is no guarantee that the user will use the app every day.

The only approach I can think of is creating 30 data columns in the database, one for each of the last 30 days. Then, at midnight, a Cloud Code function will automatically run and shift all the values into the column to the left.

I'm wondering if there's a better way that can store all this data in one data column instead of 30.

Comment: How about storing that information on the users device?

Comment: The data needs to be available online

Comment: Well, parse allows to store arrays in PFObjects. That could be a workaround.

Comment: The array still needs to be shifted every day, so I'm not sure if it that's less messy

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly convoluted question, that isn't really appropriate for a stackoverflow question. You're essentially asking someone to design your database for you from scratch. That being said, here is a suggestion in dot-point form to get you started on what your required functionality is :

- Have an object on your DB called swallowCount. Add a date field.
- Have an object on your DB for your users. Add a field to the user class that is an array of swallowCounts.
- Create a background job, to run once a day and cycle through each user. Have the background job create a swallowCount object for that day for that user. Add this swallowCount to the users array of swallowCounts.
- Create an afterSave method for the user. When the user is saved, check the length of the array of swallowCounts. If the length is > 30, remove the earliest swallowCount object from the array (via the date field).

Hopefully that helps you get started. It is difficult(impossible) to provide code examples of how to do what you want, since the question is so broad.